# Thread stack overflow

Tags: c, stack-overflow, task, vxworks

In RTOses like vxworks whenever we create a task the stacksize is specified . Can we write a routine in C which checks if the stack is overflowing or not for the task ?

Comment: Wow, a question with the "stackoverflow" tag that actually involves, you know, a stack over flowing... (Sorry, I have nothing useful to say)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your compiler they often let you add prelude functions to do this or they they might even check it themself unless you manipulate the stack pointer register.

And check if the operating system allows you to install "guard-pages". Mark the last page in your threads stack as non-read/non-write and catch the SIGSEGV signal and use a OS/CPU specific way to find out if it is the guard-page that failed. For this to work you must be sure that the stackframe of a function (stack passed parameters, local variables and alloca allocated space) is always less then a page size otherwise you can skip over the "guard-page"
This is the best way to handle it as it has no runtime overhead during normal processing.

You see this highly OS/CPU/Compiler dependent. But i'm pretty sure that google will find useable code and helpers for this technique for all systems as it is a pretty common technique for low level programmers (for example runtime or interpreter implementors).

Comment: +1 for guard pages. maybe you could also write a magic number at the end of the las page before the guard page and have a SGSEGV handler that checks to see if it was overwritten (so you can discern between stack overflows and other segfaults)

Comment: Not sure if this works in VxWorks. Many VxWorks systems just run flat memory with no MM, and thread stacks are just malloc'd

Answer (score 3):

If you know how big the stack is, and if you are careful, then yes (but not portably).  If there is no other way to obtain the base address of stack, you need to record the address of a stack variable in the thread's main function; this gives you an approximation to the top of the stack.  Then, in your checking function, you take the address of a local variable; this gives you the bottom of the stack.  If the difference between the top and the bottom is about your stack size, it is time to worry; if the difference is bigger than the stack size, it is too late to worry - the damage has been done (but now you need to think about how to clean up).

Comment: Useful, but it's more common to want a non-intrusive way of stack-checking from *another* thread - User code may not overflow, but if you start calling complex OS filesystem or networking functions, they are most likely to be the ones that eat your stack.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, you can do something like this from the shell in VxWorks using checkStack().

Answer (score 0):

There's a few techniques you can use - typically you have a low-priority task which sniffs the stack status of all other tasks every second or so.

a: Make sure the stack space is filled with a known pattern before your task starts. You can then find out how much 'uncorrupted' stack is left by checking for the pattern.

- Advantage: Lets you check the"high-watermark" of stack use.
- Disadvantage: If you allocate stack memory, but don't write to it for some reason, this technique MAY not detect the overflow.

b: You can simply sniff the stack pointer of all other threads.

- Disadvantage: This is just "sampling" the stack pointer, so a brief dip into overflow may not be noticed
- Advantage: Quick and easy.

I'd recommend a combination of both. Because you're doing lowlevel stuff using things like the VxWorks TaskInfoGet() functions, it's difficult to make this even remotely portable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VxWorks, but my recollection is that Green Hill's Velosity/uVelosity kernels provide code to do this. Even if they didn't, since they provide source that users can modify, and the infrastructure is there, it would be really easy to add.

Edit: For the sake of disclosure, I did a summer internship with them, porting uVelosity to a new architecture. This is how I became intimate with its handling of thread stacks.

Answer (score 0):

If your particular application statically allocates its threads, then it's possible to place their stacks in statically defined areas, and use a linker map to place a symbol at the end of those areas. Then, you just need to get your current stack pointer (as described in other answers) and compare the "end of stack segment" pointer to that address. This can also work for dynamic allocation, if each thread has some place to store an address provided to it as the end of its stack.

Answer (score -2):

C doesn't offer you any way of doing that, however you can still do it by making some assumptions about the underlying system.

On Windows, stack size defaults to 1MB, unless specified otherwise on the compiler, and is always aligned with a round memory address. Based on this information you can estimate the remaining stack with a function like this:

```
unsigned long remaining_stack_size() {
    char dummy;
    return 0x000fffff & (unsigned long)&dummy;
    // 0x000fffff is 1MB -1 (1048576 -1)
}
```

Note that it actually returns the current stack address, which is the same thing as it's remaining size because the stack pointer decreases as it fills.

Proof of concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

unsigned long remaining_stack_size() {
    char dummy;
    return 0x001fffff & (unsigned long)&dummy + 1; // okay, some minor adjusts
}

void recurse_to_death(unsigned long used, char *p) {
    char buf[32*1024];
    used += 32*1024;
    printf("Used: 0x%08x Remaining: 0x%08x\n", used, remaining_stack_size());
    recurse_to_death(used, buf);
}

DWORD WINAPI my_thread(void *p) {
    printf("Total stack size of this Thread: 0x%08x bytes\n", remaining_stack_size() + 72);
    recurse_to_death(0, NULL);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv) {
    DWORD tid;
    // CreateThread's stack size actually defaults to 1MB+64KB and does not honor lower values
    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, my_thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    Sleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

`remaining_stack_size()` will predict a stack overflow just as the remaining size converges to `0`.

Comment: The current stack position is NOT the same thing. It's just an address in memory. You need to know the addresses of stack top or bottom, as well as the size, to know using this technique. -1

Comment: Actually I know what I'm doing here, try it.

Comment: You know so well that you provided an answer applicable on Windows to a question specifically asking about VxWorks.

Comment: What's aplicable to Windows is not the answer.